# Is there a standalone Clojure package within Leiningen?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

After installing leiningen with this script https://raw.github.com/technomancy/leiningen/preview/bin/lein , I can use the **repl** by typing `lein repl`, so I think the **clojure** has already been installed by **leiningen**.

Do I need to download the JAR of the clojure again from the offical site?

If there's no need to do this, where's the JAR file of **clojure** that **leiningten** depends on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I've found with lein is installing it and then depending on a specific version of Clojure causes that version to be fetched, and the .jar file winds up in the maven repository.

```
(defproject repl-test "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "TODO: add summary of your project"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]
                 [clojure-csv/clojure-csv "1.3.2"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.cli "0.1.0"]
                 [util "1.0.2-SNAPSHOT"]
                 [clj-http "0.1.3"]]
   :aot [repl-test.core]
   :main repl-test.core)
```

I'm not sure how Clojure is packaged with lein, but I do know from watching a lein build that it causes the version of Clojure in `:dependencies` to be fetched (downloaded).

lein is so good, that I actually un-installed default Clojure, because having lein is less of a pain when Clojure goes into a new revision.

Comment: Thanks, but I have another question following this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064339/how-to-run-clojure-as-a-script-using-leningen

Answer (score 6):

leiningen downloads dependencies from maven repositories and stores them (by default) in

```
${HOME}/.m2/repository
```

leiningen stores it's own jar in

```
${HOME}/.lein/self-installs
```

the default maven repositories searched by leiningen are

- maven central (which you can browse at http://search.maven.org)
- clojars (which you can browse at http://clojars.org)

Comment: You mention "by default" for where leiningen stores dependencies. Is there a way to customize that location? I don't want these in my local maven.

Comment: Nix that question. You can specify the `:local-build` in project.clj.

Answer (score 0):

Leiningen is a tool that manages Clojure (and Java) libraries for you --- including Clojure itself (which is just another Java library (a jar)).

You don't need to manually download any jars when using lein.

Leiningen consists of two parts: the `lein` script and an implementation jar that it keeps in ~/.lein --- but you don't need to worry about that jar; the `lein` script takes care of getting it for you.

I wrote a [Brief Beginner's Guide](http://www.unexpected-vortices.com/clojure/brief-beginners-guide/) which you might find useful.