# How to run .clj file as a script using leningen?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

This is the second question after [Is there a standalone Clojure package within Leiningen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064001/is-there-a-standalone-clojure-package-within-leiningen/12064211#12064211)

For example, I have a file `hello_world.clj`, and I can run it using

`java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main hello_world.clj`.

Since **lein** already contains **Clojure** (because I can run `lein repl` directly), is there a way to do the same thing like

`lein script hello_world.clj` by lein?

Comment: do you mean lein run? https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen#basic-usage

Comment: @georgek Maybe not as `lein run` needs the `project.clj` created.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

use [lein-exec](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-exec) plugin, example from readme.md (updated with "lein" instead of "lein2")

```
cat foo.clj | lein exec
lein exec -e '(println "foo" (+ 20 30))'
lein exec -ep "(use 'foo.bar) (pprint (map baz (range 200)))"
lein exec -p script/run-server.clj -p 8088
lein exec ~/common/delete-logs.clj
```

Answer (score 41):

There are several ways with `lein repl`:

- Very slow: `cat your_file.clj | lein repl`
- Slow: `echo '(load-file "your_file.clj")' | lein repl`
- Fast:

  1. `lein repl`
  2. `(load-file "your_file.clj")`
  3. repeat `2`

Comment: The "fast" one didn't work for me. Had to instead use '(clojure.main/load-script "test.clj")'

Answer (score 8):

leiningen can create an 'uberjar' for you with all your dependencies....

```
lein uberjar
```

will create a jar for you in the target subdirectory. The jar will contain all the dependencies listed in your `project.clj`, so you don't need to worry about constructing a complex classpath to invoke your code.

You can reference this uberjar as a single entry in your java classpath in the normal way or, specify a main-class in the `project.clj` invoke it as an executable jar.

e.g. a `project.clj` like this:

```
(defproject clj-scratch "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
 :description "FIXME: write description"
 :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]                     
 :main clj-scratch.core)
```

will invoke the `-main` function in `clj-scratch.core namespace`

if you run:

```
java -jar target/clj-scratch-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [inlein](https://github.com/hypirion/inlein) for that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env inlein

'{:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [com.hypirion/primes "0.2.1"]]}

(require '[com.hypirion.primes :as p])

(when-not (first *command-line-args*)
  (println "Usage:" (System/getProperty "$0") "prime-number")
  (System/exit 1))

(-> (first *command-line-args*)
    (Long/parseLong)
    (p/get)
    println)
```

Then just `chmod +x script.clj` and run it!

Alternatively you can just `inlein script.clj my args here` as well.